# Counting minimum elements needed such that their sum covers the whole finite space.

Tags: combinatorics, finite-fields, extremal-combinatorics

In $\mathbb{F}_p$, how to find a subset with smallest cardinality such that the sum between its pairs cover $\mathbb{F}_p\setminus\{0\}$.
So for a subset with cardinality $n$ there are ${n\choose 2}$ pairs and correspondingly ${n\choose 2}$ sums. I want $n$ to be smallest such that those ${n\choose 2}$ sums cover $\mathbb{F}_p\setminus\{0\}$.

For example in $\mathbb{F}_7$, let $A=\{0,1,2,4\}$,
The sums between its pairs covers $\mathbb{F}_7\setminus\{0\}$ since
\begin{align*} 
0+1=1,0+2=2,1+2=3,0+4=4,1+4=5,2+4=6\;.
\end{align*}
I want to know if over large $p$ similar set can be easily constructed and what would be the size of that set (I expect it to be close to $\sqrt{2p}$). Any similar literature is also appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Do the pairs need to be distinct? If not, then for $p=7$ the set $\{1,2,4\}$ suffices.

Comment: @Servaes: the OP says there are ${n \choose 2}$ sums which implies they need to be distinct. It would also be interesting to consider the variant where they don't need to be distinct.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan You are right. It would be nice to have this made explicit though, as the case where they need not be distinct is more commonly studied, I believe. Of course this doesn't affect the asymptotic behaviour.

Comment: @Alex: ah, fantastic, thank you!

Comment: @Bored-panda you write $1 + 5 = 6$, but $5 \notin A$. However $2 + 4 = 6$ would be correct

Answer (score 4):

You can solve the problem via integer linear programming as follows.  For $i\in \{0,\dots,n-1\}$, let binary decision variable $x_i$ indicate whether $i$ is selected.  For $0 \le i < j \le n-1$, let binary decision variable $y_{i,j}$ represent the product $x_i x_j$.  The problem is to minimize $\sum_i x_i$ subject to
\begin{align}
\sum_{\substack{0 \le i < j \le n-1:\\ i + j = k}} y_{i,j} &\ge 1 &&\text{for $k \in \{1,\dots,n-1\}$} \tag1 \\
y_{i,j} &\le x_i &&\text{for $0 \le i < j \le n-1$} \tag2 \\
y_{i,j} &\le x_j &&\text{for $0 \le i < j \le n-1$} \tag3
\end{align}
Constraint $(1)$ forces each sum $k$ to be covered.
Constraints $(2)$ and $(3)$ enforce the logical implication $y_{i,j} \implies (x_i \land x_j)$.

The values for $n \in \{1,\dots,50\}$ are
$$
\begin{matrix}
0 &2 &3 &3 &4 &4 &4 &5 &5 &5\\
6 &6 &6 &6 &7 &7 &7 &7 &8 &8 \\
8 &8 &8 &9 &9 &9 &9 &9 &10 &10 \\
10 &10 &10 &10 &11 &11 &11 &11 &11 &11\\
11 &12 &12 &12 &12 &12 &12 &12 &13 &13
\end{matrix}
$$
[image]

If you change the condition to $(i+j) \mod n = k$ in constraint $(1)$, the values for $n \in\{1,\dots,50\}$ are instead
\begin{matrix}
0 &2 &3 &3 &4 &4 &4 &5 &5 &5 \\
5 &6 &6 &6 &7 &7 &7 &7 &7 &7 \\
8 &8 &8 &8 &8 &9 &9 &9 &9 &9 \\
9 &10 &10 &10 &10 &10 &10 &11 &11 &11 \\
11 &11 &11 &11 &12 &12 &12 &12 &12 &12
\end{matrix}
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you working $\bmod n$ here? It's slightly confusing because the OP uses $n$ to mean something else. Also, it looks like the answer is close to $\sqrt{\pi n}$.

Comment: This sequence doesn't appear to be in the OEIS but the following related sequence A046693 is and solves a very similar problem: http://oeis.org/A046693

Comment: The results here did not use $\mod n$.  The only change to the optimization model would be the $i+j=k$ in the summation index for constraint $(1)$.

Comment: If you want to take the time I'd be interested in seeing what the results are like $\bmod n$, and in particular seeing if the sequence is in the OEIS!

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I added the $\mod n$ results just now.

Answer (score 2):

Nice question! First, as in RobPratt's answer I'll generalize to the non-prime case. Rob discusses two variants of the question both of which seem quite interesting to me: the first is to find a set of non-negative integers of minimal size whose distinct pairwise sums cover $\{ 1, \dots n-1 \}$, and the second is the same question but working $\bmod n$. For lack of better notation let me call these $f_{+}(n)$ and $f_{cyc}(n)$. Neither of them appear to be in the OEIS but [A046693](http://oeis.org/A046693) has similar values and is related, answering a similar question but about pairwise differences rather than sums; "[perfect ruler](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PerfectRuler.html)" may be a useful keyword here. If we allow sums of the same element then we are studying the [sumset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sumset) from additive combinatorics and there may be useful tools there also.

We clearly have $f_{cyc}(n) \le f_{+}(n)$. Interestingly we also have $f_{+}(n) \le f_{+}(n-1) + 1$ since if we can cover $\{ 1, \dots n-1 \}$ we need at most one new integer to cover $\{ 1, \dots n \}$, suggesting that the integer version of the problem may have more usable inductive structure. The "information-theoretic lower bound" is

$$f_L(n) \le f_{cyc}(n) \le f_{+}(n)$$

where $f_L(n)$ is the smallest nonnegative integer $k$ such that ${k \choose 2} \ge n-1$, or equivalently $(2k - 1)^2 \ge 8n - 7$, hence

$$f_L(n) = \left\lceil \frac{\sqrt{8n-7} + 1}{2} \right\rceil \approx \sqrt{2n}.$$

(The above formula doesn't work for $n = 1$.) $f_L(n)$ is just the sequence $0, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, \dots $ which, after the somewhat degenerate value $0$, takes the value $k$ a total of $k-1$ times. This lower bound is achievable iff it is possible to find a subset of the above sum whose distinct pairwise sums cover $\{ 1, \dots n-1 \}$ exactly once each. According to Rob's data the first point at which $f_L(n) < f_{+}(n)$ is $n = 11$, where $f_L(11) = 5$ but $f_{+}(11) = 6$, and the first point at which $f_L(n) < f_{cyc}(n)$ is $n = 15$, where $f_L(15) = 6$  but $f_{cyc}(15) = 7$.

Here is the best upper bound I have so far. The construction is quite simple but all of the more complicated constructions I've come up with so far have done worse!

> **Proposition:**

> $$f_{+}(n) \le \text{min} \left( 2 \lceil \sqrt{n} \rceil - 1, 2 \left\lceil \frac{ \sqrt{4n+1} - 1}{2} \right\rceil \right).$$

*Proof.* Let $k, \ell$ be positive integers. Every integer in the interval $[0, k \ell - 1]$ can be written uniquely in the form $ak + b$ where $0 \le b \le k-1, 0 \le a \le \ell - 1$. It follows that if we take $S = \{ ak : 0 \le a \le \ell - 1 \} \cup \{ b : 0 \le b \le k - 1 \}$, which has size $k + \ell - 1$, then distinct pairwise sums of elements of $S$ cover $\{ 1, \dots k \ell - 1 \}$.

So we want to chose $k$ and $\ell$ such that $k + \ell - 1$ is as small as possible subject to the constraint that $k \ell \ge n$. Standard arguments imply that this means we want to choose $k$ and $\ell$ to be as close as possible. If we take $k = \ell = \lceil \sqrt{n} \rceil$ then this gives $f_{+}(n) \le 2 \lceil \sqrt{n} \rceil - 1$, which was the bound I had previously written down here.

But actually it is possible to do a little better than this for some values of $n$ by taking $\ell = k-1$. Then $k(k-1) \ge n$ gives $(2k-1)^2 \ge 4n+1$ which gives

$$k = \left\lceil \frac{ \sqrt{4n+1} + 1}{2} \right\rceil$$

and hence

$$f_{+}(n) \le 2k-2 = 2 \left\lceil \frac{ \sqrt{4n+1} - 1}{2} \right\rceil.$$

which is occasionally better, e.g. when $n = 50$ (the worst case for the $2 \lceil \sqrt{n} \rceil - 1$ bound, one larger than a perfect square) the original bound gives $15$ but this bound gives $14$. With a little more effort we should be able to characterize when one bound or the other is better. $\Box$

So, in summary, we have

$$\boxed{ \left\lceil \frac{\sqrt{8n-7} + 1}{2} \right\rceil \le f_{cyc}(n) \le f_{+}(n) \le \text{min} \left( 2 \lceil \sqrt{n} \rceil - 1, 2 \left\lceil \frac{ \sqrt{4n+1} - 1}{2} \right\rceil \right) }.$$

Rob's data implies that neither the upper nor the lower bound is sharp, although for $2 \le n \le 50$ it does give that the upper bound is sharp for $f_{+}(n)$ when $n$ or $4n+1$ is a perfect square. I am very curious if this will continue to be true. (**Edit:** Rob checked in the comments and it fails for $n = 64$. Welp!) For easier comparison with Rob's data here's a table of the upper bound for $n \in \{ 1, \dots 50 \}$, with points where it differs from $f_{+}(n)$ highlighted in red (in each case it's off by $1$):

$$
\begin{matrix}
\color{red}{1} &2 &3 &3 &4 &4 & \color{red}{5} &5 &5 & \color{red}{6}\\
6 &6 & \color{red}{7} & \color{red}{7} &7 &7 &\color{red}{8} &\color{red}{8} &8 &8 \\
\color{red}{9} & \color{red}{9} & \color{red}{9} &9 &9 & \color{red}{10} & \color{red}{10} & \color{red}{10} &10 &10 \\
\color{red}{11} & \color{red}{11} & \color{red}{11} & \color{red}{11} &11 &11 & \color{red}{12} & \color{red}{12} & \color{red}{12} & \color{red}{12}\\
 \color{red}{12} &12 & \color{red}{13} & \color{red}{13} & \color{red}{13} & \color{red}{13} & \color{red}{13} & \color{red}{13} &13 & \color{red}{14}
\end{matrix}
$$

And here's a graph generated in Google Sheets:

[image]

It would be good to have empirical evidence for larger values of $n$. I don't know if Rob's approach will give, say, $n = 100$ or $n = 1000$, but I think larger values of $n$ should be approachable by just generating subsets randomly and checking their pairwise sums; for subsets close to the optimal bound this should work with high probability. The probabilistic method was the first thing I tried to write down a bound but I couldn't make it work.

As a concrete challenge I'd love to see if anyone could offer better upper or lower bounds than the above for $n = 100$ or $n = 1000$. You could take $n = 101$ or $n = 1009$ if you want to stick to primes. The lower and upper bounds here are, respectively,

$$15 \le f_{cyc}(100) \le f_{+}(100) \le 19$$
$$15 \le f_{cyc}(101) \le f_{+}(101) \le 20$$
$$46 \le f_{cyc}(1000) \le f_{+}(1000) \le 63$$
$$46 \le f_{cyc}(1009) \le f_{+}(1009) \le 63.$$

**Edit:** Lots of stuff including some references in this [very closely related but not entirely identical question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2536952/sumset-that-covers-mathbbz-p-mathbbz/), which considers sumsets and so allows non-distinct sums, and also asks to cover $0$; this is arguably more natural (e.g. it gives the problem more symmetries). These are called [sum covers](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.83.9742) or finite [additive bases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_basis). Fitch and Jamison's *[Minimum sum covers of small cyclic groups](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.83.9742)* opens with more or less the same bounds as above, considers both distinct and non-distinct sums, and has a table of values and of optimal covers for $3 \le n \le 54$.

Comment: $f_+(8^2)=14<2\cdot 8-1$

Comment: @Rob: thanks! Guess that was too much to hope for then.

Comment: @Rob: whoops, thanks, yes. I was trying to take the smallest primes greater than $100$ and $1000$ respectively.

Comment: $f_+(100) = 18$.

Comment: $f_+(101) \le 18$.

Comment: The following two sequences give a kind of dual result (largest $m$ such that $1,\dots,m$ is representable as a pair sum): https://oeis.org/A004129 ($f_+$) and https://oeis.org/A004131 ($f_\text{cyc}$)

Comment: $f_+(101) = 18$.

Answer (score 2):

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2536952/sumset-that-covers-mathbbz-p-mathbbz) thread I [answered](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2536952/sumset-that-covers-mathbbz-p-mathbbz/2552130#2552130) a similar question for sumsets. Some of results mentioned in the thread can be applicable to this question. Namely, lower size sumsets bounds for $\Bbb Z$ provide lower bounds for $f_+(n)$  (see the beginning of Qiaochu Yuan’s [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3974975/counting-minimum-elements-needed-such-that-their-sum-covers-the-whole-finite-spa/3982966#3982966) for the definition of $f_+(n)$).:

> it seems that in this direction was mainly investigated the Z counterpart of the problem, for which is devoted a lot of papers, in which the lower bound was more and more improved by complicated techniques, see, for instance [Mos], [GN], [Hor], [Yu].

I am checking the mentioned papers, but I already can say that the results of [Mos] imply that $f_+(n)>\sqrt{\tfrac {2n-2}{1-.0197}}$ for sufficiently large $n$.

> I also found that another my colleague, Oleg Pikhurko dealt with a related stuff in his paper [Pih]. In particular, he noted that Mrose [Mro] constructed a set $S\subset [0, 10t^2+8t]$ of size $7t + 3$ such that $S + S\supset [0, 14t^2 + 10t − 1]$. In fact, $S$ is the union of ﬁve disjoint arithmetic progressions, see the description at p. 6 of Pikhurko’s paper.

Since sums of  distinct elements of $S$ cover the discrete segment $[0, 14t^2 + 10t − 1]$ but a number $8t^2+4t-2$, see the last paragraph of [Pih, p.6], we can add one element to the set $S$ and obtain a set $S’$ such that sums of distinct elements of $S’$ cover the discrete segment $[0, 14t^2 + 10t − 1]$, which follows $f_+(14t^2 + 10t)\le 7t +4$.

This fact provides an upper bound for $f_+(n)$ as follows. Pick the smallest natural $t$ such that $14t^2+10t\ge n$. Then $n\ge 14(t-1)^2+10(t-1)+1=14t^2-18t+5$. Solving the respective quadratic equation, we see that for $n\ge 4$ we have $t\le\tfrac {9+\sqrt{56n-199}}{28}$ and so $$f_+(n)\le 7t+4\le \frac{25+\sqrt{56n-199}}{4}.$$

*References*

[GN] C. Sinan Güntürk, Melvyn B. Nathanson *[A new upper bound for finite additive bases](https://www.impan.pl/en/publishing-house/journals-and-series/acta-arithmetica/all/124/3/83886/a-new-upper-bound-for-finite-additive-bases)*, Acta Arithmetica **124** (2006), 235-255.

[Hor] G. Horváth *[An improvement of an estimate for finite additive bases](https://www.impan.pl/en/publishing-house/journals-and-series/acta-arithmetica/all/130/4/82399/an-improvement-of-an-estimate-for-finite-additive-bases)*, Acta Arithmetica **130** (2007), 369-380.

[Mos] L. Moser [On the representation of $1,2,\dots, n$ by sums](https://www.impan.pl/pl/wydawnictwa/czasopisma-i-serie-wydawnicze/acta-arithmetica/all/6/1/94480/on-the-representation-of-1-2-n-by-sums), Acta Arithmetica **6** (1960), 11-13.

[Pih] Oleg Pikhurko *[Dense Edge-Magic Graphs and Thin Additive Bases](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0309029)*.

[Yu] Gang Yu *[Upper bounds for finite additive $2$-bases](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2009-137-01/S0002-9939-08-09430-6/)*, Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. **137** (2009), 11-18.

Comment: Thanks! if I'm reading it right, that construction of Mrose implies $\liminf_{n \to \infty} \frac{f_{+}(n)}{\sqrt{n}} \le \sqrt{ \frac{7}{2} } \approx 1.87 \dots$, yes?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Even better, see the updated answer.